# How to ensure load observable data before rendering reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on reactive form, form-group in Angular 5 application. I am getting data via API that subscribe with observable. My issue is my formGroup try to load data while is not there and throw exception. I need to ensure loadData() load data before formGroup initialise.

### Component

```
export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
@Input() questionsList: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
@Input() questionsMappedList: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
form: FormGroup;

private view: BehaviorSubject<QuestionsDataModel>;
private consultationQuestions: QuestionsDataModel;

constructor(private dataService: QuestionsDataService, private router: Router, private session: SessionStorageService, private qcs: QuestionControlService, private questionService: QuestionMappingService) {

  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.view = new BehaviorSubject<QuestionsDataModel>(null);
    this.loadData();
    this.questions = this.questionService.getQuestions();
    //this.questions = this.questionService.getQuestionList(null);
     this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions); 
}

public loadData():void
{

    //filtersLoaded: Promise<boolean>;

  var consultationId = this.session.getItem('consultationId');

   this.dataService.getQuestions(consultationId)
   .subscribe(data =>{
     debugger;
        this.view.next(data);
        this.questionsList = this.questionService.getQuestionList(data);
        console.log("dynamic questionsList...", this.questionsList);

   });
}
```

### template

```
<div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">

      <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
        <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
      <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why dont you just call `this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions); ` after you get data, and combine if with `*ngIf="form"` in the template?

Comment: I am very new to angular, if I do that, I got error ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

Comment: Something for you to read: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a boolean condition on ngOnInit..

```
private formData = false;
```

Then inside your loadData function do...

```
loadData() {

            this.formData = true;
```

Then in your template do..

```
<form *nGIf='formData'>
```

Or simply do..

```
<form *nGIf='myFormDataVariables' >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize form in `ngOnInit` and then update its values after API call.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.view = new BehaviorSubject<QuestionsDataModel>(null);
    this.loadData();
    this.questions = this.questionService.getQuestions();
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      sampleProperty: '',
      // init form values
    });
}
```

---

```
public loadData(): void {
  var consultationId = this.session.getItem('consultationId');

   this.dataService.getQuestions(consultationId)
   .subscribe(data =>{
     debugger;
        this.view.next(data);
        this.questionsList = this.questionService.getQuestionList(data);

        this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions); 
   });
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it, how I initialise form value, and what will be in sampleProperty ? sorry for asking silly I am very new to angular

Comment: You can ignore sampleProperty as it's only example. Add your this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions) function to question, then I can help to build that form.

Comment: We need QuestionControlService to help.